# custom field value which can change css class in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I have created portfolio page type in wordpress-theme with 3 column layout for portfolio item's. I want to create meta-box with drop down to select column number for portfolio list item (may be Images), so I can change column number from 1 column to 4 column layout. I have  css class for list item which is responsible for 3 column layout. How can I change css class for list Item with custom field value to change number of column layout.

Comment: Post some of your code. It will be easier for people to help you if they can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Create your custom field. Let's say "number_of_columns". Type your values in this custom field on each page. 
Then in your page template, just use `get_post_meta` to output the value in a CSS rule name, like this :

```
<div class="<?php get_post_meta($postid, 'number_of_columns', true); ?>_column_layout">
Create the layout here with the n_column_layout CSS class...
</div>
```

There you go. If number_of_columns was 2, you will get a div with the 2_column_layout class, etc. Right answer?

Comment: Yeah Thanks so much. I got what I want. Now I am just implementing it through meta-box with dropdown in my template.